# Angular - Mat Table, getting the sum of selected row values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat table in which I can select each rows and process it.
I don't have a problem when I select and process a single one, however, I'm stuck for hours thinking of a way if I click up to 3 values (maximum)

[image]

I was able to get their values and put them in an array by adding a mat-check-box

HTML goes like this

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox 
            (change)="multiPayment(row)"
            (click)="singlePayment(row)" > 
         </mat-checkbox>
         </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

TS goes like this

```
  // Single Payment
  singlePayment(row:unpaidModel) {
    this.detailstoPay = rows;
  }

  // gets multi payment
  multiPayment(multiRows:unpaidModel) {
     if (!this.rowChecker.includes(multiRows)) {
       this.rowChecker.push(multiRows)
     } else {
       this.rowChecker.splice(this.rowChecker.indexOf(multiRows),1)
     }
    console.log(this.rowChecker);
  }
```

results:

[image]

Array is not really my strong point, however I just want to know how I could get specific values in the array like the price of each and store it on another variable.

Comment: why are you calling two methods with checkbox ?

Comment: I would like to get the price for each row, display and store it individually,

for example, If I click c123, price 80 is stored in a variable totalPrice, now when I click c122, the price is stored as well in the same variable totalPrice and their values will add in totalPrice making it to 160. Then if I save it, they will still be counted as cluster 1 and cluster 2

Comment: Thank you for this one you're a lifesaver~ now the only problem I have is how to save them individually in my firestore. If you still have the time to help me, i'll promise to buy you cups.

Comment: Sure! How can I assist on this? @CarloA